# What are the factors that affect Android app's installation time consumption?

Tags: android, installation

Recently I'm making an app which requires being downloaded and installed instantly. It's obviously that the smaller the APK's size are, the faster it can be downloaded. So I'm wondering what affects the installation speed? Is it only related to the APK's size or there's other factors I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

The major factors in APK size are libraries and media used in the App.

You should have to read this official documentation :

[Reduce APK size](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html)

Also understand the concept of various screen resolution because.it also leads to variation in APK size.

[Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)